# groups with infinitely many ends are not boundedly generated?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory

Recall that a group $G$ is [boundedly generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundedly_generated_group) if it can be written as a finite product of cyclic subgroups. And there are a lot of examples of groups that are (not) boundedly generated.

I am wondering whether it is true that if $G$ has infinitely many ends, then it is not boundedly generated.

Comment: Such groups are acylindrically hyperbolic (coming from the Bass-Serre action), and I believe Osin proved that acylindrically hyperbolic groups are not boundedly generated. (I don't have time to look up references at the moment or give a more detailed answer) There might be an earlier reference coming from the groups being relatively hyperbolic.

Comment: @PaulPlummer, I guess you are talking about Theorem 1.9 in Osin's paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404118, I think we may use the even stronger theorem proved in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601590

Comment: closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781401/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Paul's comments that brings Osin's work to my attention, now, I realized that I should have known the answer is yes from the following argument.

---

First, from Proposition 7.1 in Peterson-Thom's paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4327), we know that if $G$ is boundedly generated in the above sense, then the first $\ell^2$-Betti number of $G$ is equal to zero.

Now, suppose $G$ has infinitely many ends, we know $G$ contains non-abelian free group $F_2$ as a subgroup (by Osin's paper above), hence $G$ is not amenable; then $H^1(G, \ell^2(G))=0$ from Peterson-Thom's above paper, so the subgroup $H^1(G, \mathbb{Z}G)=0$, which is equivalently to saying that $G$ has one-end, a contradiction.